# how can I use ngrok to a subfolder of localhost

Tags: iis, ngrok

I want to use ngrok to display a web site in IIS, the site is not located in default website (http://localhost) but in a subfolder as an application in IIS like this...

```
localhost
  --wordpress
```

And I can the access that site like this http://localhost/wordpress/ when browsing locally

How can I use ngrok to point to this folder, the only thing I get to work is `ngrok http 80`
but that only display the content of default web site (localhost) and that is not what I want to show, I want to expose the localhost/wordpress folder. Can that be done?

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful  to you, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use URL Rewrite to rewrite ***http://localhost/*** to ***http://localhost/wordpress/***:

```
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/wordpress/{URL}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

[image]